# Sockets Java/PHP Transferring data slowly

Tags: java, php, sockets, bukkit

I am transferring String data through sockets, the data transfers perfectly but slowly.

My Java Client has the following code (It is a bukkit server plugin):

```
while(true) {
                try {
                    ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(25560);
                    Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
                    InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

                    String MESSAGE = BR.readLine();
                    System.out.println(MESSAGE);

                    if (MESSAGE != null) {
                        PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
                        String data = "";
                        data += "{";
                        data += "\"server\": {";
                        data += "\"name\": \"" + getConfig().getString("data.name") + "\",";
                        data += "\"onlineplayers\": \"" + String.valueOf(getServer().getOnlinePlayers().length) + "\",";
                        data += "\"maxplayers\": \"" + String.valueOf(getServer().getMaxPlayers()) + "\"";                                      
                        data += "}";
                        data += "}";
                        data += "}";
                        System.out.println(data);
                        PS.println(data);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
```

The Data String ends up holding the value `{"server": {"name": "Gaming Node 2","onlineplayers": "1","maxplayers": "20"}}}`

And my PHP client has the following code:

```
    <?php

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

//Connect socket to remote server
if(!socket_connect($sock ,gethostbyname("Ip.address.com"), 25560))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Connection established \n";

$message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";

//Send the message to the server
if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Message send successfully \n";

//Now receive reply from server
if(socket_recv ( $sock , $buf , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

//print the received message
echo $buf;
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

The data is transferred successfully but takes about 10 seconds.  If I make the data string on the java side shorter, to maybe a word, it takes about 1.5 seconds.  I don't think this is a network connection speed issue because they are both running on the same machine (do I need to write local host in the php script area to take advantage of the fact that they are on the same machine?).  How do I make the transfer of data faster?

Comment: Didnt really change the speed at all

Comment: Try `PS.flush();` after `PS.println(data);` (in general with Java networking: always flush after a message is put on the line).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Java Bridges?
Try this: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/